# DataSet incorrectly interprets a XSD with duplicate element names

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xsd, dataset

We currently use the .NET DataSet.ReadXmlSchema() function to convert a XML schema into a relational structure. This worked fine for us until now. A customer of ours supplied us with a XSD that seemed to convert alright until we noticed that some fields were missing in the resulting DataSet.

I have created a simplified version of this XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:element name="Document" type="Document"/>
    <xs:complexType name="Document">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Customer" maxOccurs="100" minOccurs="0" type="Person"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="PersonIdentifier">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="CompositePersonId1" type="xs:integer"/>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="CompositePersonId2" type="xs:integer"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="LocationIdentifier">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="CompositeLocationId1" type="xs:integer"/>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="CompositeLocationId2" type="xs:integer"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="Person">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="Id" type="PersonIdentifier"/>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="Name" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="SurName" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="Age" type="xs:integer"/>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="HouseAddress" type="Address"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="Address">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="Id" type="LocationIdentifier"/>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="Street" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="HouseNo" type="xs:integer"/>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="HouseNoAd" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="City" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

The DataSet accepts this schema and at first glance all seems to be okay. When we convert these structures to actual SQL tables (don't ask...) a problem becomes apparent:

```
create table Document(
    Document_Id INT NULL
);

create table Customer(
    Name VARCHAR(100) NULL,
    SurName VARCHAR(100) NULL,
    Age INT NULL,
    Customer_Id INT NULL,
    Document_Id INT NULL
);

create table Id(
    CompositePersonId1 INT NULL,
    CompositePersonId2 INT NULL,
    HouseAddress_Id INT NULL,
    Customer_Id INT NULL
);

create table HouseAddress(
    Street VARCHAR(100) NULL,
    HouseNo INT NULL,
    HouseNoAd VARCHAR(10) NULL,
    City VARCHAR(100) NULL,
    HouseAddress_Id INT NULL,
    Customer_Id INT NULL
);
```

The DataSet has created a separate table for the Id field of Person as it is a ComplexType (PersonIdentifier). It has failed to do so for the Id field of Address, which is a ComplexType named LocationIdentifier. Instead, the DataSet assumes that the Id field of Person and Address are of the same type, and it has linked Address to the same Id table.

The net effect of this is that the CompositeLocationId1 and CompositeLocationId2 fields are nowhere to be found in the resulting data structures. This is a problem for us as we rely on this functionality.

Just to be clear, editing the XSD is not an option as it is supplied by the customer. The customer is unlikely to edit his XSD at it is supplied by a major third party.

I basically see no other option than looking for an alternative for the DataSet functionality or building something on our own.